# Spring + Jackson Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

When posting with jQuery ajax, I get following error.

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:226)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:148)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:125)
```

The interesting thing is when I debug

```
RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:148
```

and get the `webRequest.getHeader("Content-Type")` the value is `application/json`. Which is pretty normal.

But when it comes to the last method of the chain `AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:226` Content-Type becomes `application/json; charset=utf-8;`

Which throws an exception. Here is my code ;

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/set-preference",method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
private boolean set_preference(@RequestBody UserPreference preference)
{

    try{            
        userService.save(preference);

        return true;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
public class UserPreference extends BaseEntity{

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private User user;

private String name;
private String information;

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getInformation() {
    return information;
}
public void setInformation(String information) {
    this.information = information;
}


}
```

**Spring MVC Config**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean
                    class="com.test.HibernateAwareObjectMapper" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: Add `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` in your RequestMapping and then try once.

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it adding a default constructor to my class. Try it.